# Is middleware needed for a REST service to be consumed?

Tags: rest, jersey, integration, esb, mq

There is an external web-service (REST based) which provides logistics service. In order to consume it from our application (which is java stack), I created a client library (using jersey and jackson, which is a self-contained jar file, and gives simple getters and setters to work with). All that is needed to consume this REST service is this jar file (which is being used as re-usable asset).

However, one of our clients asked, "since we already have ESB (a middleware from IBM) for our existing integrations, why can we not have this integration also through ESB ?"

- Is it possible to consume the REST based service using a middleware such as ESB(or MQ) ? If so, how ?
- Will it be wise to do it ?
- What arguments can I posit to my client to tell them this may not work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Is it possible to consume the REST based service using a middleware such as ESB(or MQ) ? If so, how ? -
```

Yes. Every ESB has its syntax/APIs. Should not be difficult to understand if you are already working with REST/http requests. Note, MQ is a message broker that will allow asynchronous communication. For example, the application that wants to consume the REST service can send a message to the broker and not wait for a response from the external service. The message broker in turn can talk REST to the external service. The message broker might expose a REST interface to consume messages. But it all depends on the use case. You may want to call REST service synchronously.

Most ESBs support calling external web services REST/SOAP. So an ESB does not necessarily mean MQ.

```
Will it be wise to do it ?
```

It depends. Many organizations set up ESB/Gateway as a policy and to route/filter/govern all external routings. Also to manage load, HA etc.

```
What arguments can I posit to my client to tell them this may not work ?
```

It will most certainly work. You should assess if using an ESB is an overhead based on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you techuser for your answer. My primary concern is the REST service in question is based on **http://jsonapi.org** specification - which is not the easiest to consume. The client lirary i wrote in java, can it be re-used if we have to take the ESB route (else all that effort will be wasted) ? Are there any tutorials/information you can point me to for REST consumption via ESB. I'm afraid the link given by @Robert Maskel is very specific to Bizagi and did not help me much.Thanks again.